# Convert iPhone smileys to a website

Tags: iphone, icons

iPhone Smileys are very popular thanks to Spell Number.

I have a common database for my iPhone app and my Website and I need to convert iPhone smileys for the web.

Do you know any library or program for that?

Thanks, Théo.

Comment: I don't quite understand.  Are you talking about extracting the smiley images from the iphone and reusing them on a website?  You're probably better off finding some royalty-free smiley icons on the web and using those instead.

Comment: Yes something like that but iPhone smileys use specials char only for the iPhone and I don't know how to recognize and convert it to my Website

Answer (score 1):

what you're looking for is something that will convert the emoji codes to their web equivalents.

this is a start

https://sites.google.com/site/unicodesymbols/Home/emoji-symbols

links to the charts and their codes are provided, as well as an explanation of emoji.